# Disable keyboard animation on pushViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, iphone-softkeyboard

Is it possible to disable the keyboard animation on `pushViewController` so that the keyboard slides off with the rest of the screen (instead of sliding down while the rest of the screen slides off)?

I currently call `[[self view] endEditing: YES]` in `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` which is causing the keyboard to slide down. I don't know of a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you call that method in the viewDidDisappear: method ?

Comment: Calling it in viewDidDisappear causes the app to crash.